# How to change location of Textview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, user-interface, visibility

I have a Linear Layout inside of Constraint Layout. The cardview visibility changes depending on the data. How to align start textview1 and textview2 if cardview visibility is invisible ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make relative layout visible and hide as per your card data.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="1dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsregular"
                android:text="New Crerdentials"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsregular"
            android:text="New Crerdentials"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsregular"
            android:text="New Crerdentials"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hey you can try this**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="1dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsregular"
                android:text="New Crerdentials"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsregular"
            android:text="New Crerdentials"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsregular"
            android:text="New Crerdentials"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```